# A workflow management to integrate into my own software

Tags: open-source, library, software-development

I have a specific request from a client to provide a workflow management / business process module that mixes human and automated tasks to integrate with our own existing web-based software. So the module/software I am looking for can

- Provide modifiable and integratable web-based frontend.
- Non technical user can interactively create and see the state of an workflow
- Have backend APIs to help integrate with automated tasks
- Can integrate with custom user management system (User/Role/Right) provided from another software ( our own existing one )

Is there a software solution or a combination of softwares for this kind of requirement?

Comment: Cloud-based or on-premise (~ in-house)? . Your requirement "custom user management system " is a little bit fuzzy. can be anything. But all big 3 cloud providers work hard to make it easy to bring your own LDAP systems (for instance) into cloud based environments and there you can have what you describe in bullet points 1-3

Comment: It's in house. The end customer may or may not integrate their LDAP with our custom software. So most likely, the workflow management module will only interface with our custom software on a simple user-role-right auth implementation. I realized the first question was not clear enough to I made some modification